# Crystal Report Viewer Export window Malfunction

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, asp-classic, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a ASP.net application in which I have added a Crystal Report Viewer to view a certain report .. My problem is ..

When I click export button of Crystal Report it kind of malfunctions, below is a snop shot of it ..

[image]

Is there any key I am missing ? I have to open the reports mainly in **IE6**. Mozilla and Chrome are a plus point..

Comment: Is the the Crystal Reports Viewer? Are you opening this in a browser?

Comment: Yes .. Sorry this should have been told in the question .. Let me update my question ..

Comment: I would strongly recommend updating your IE 6 to the latest possible version and then try again.

Comment: Thanks .. IE6 is a requirement .. I resolved it .. my default css was messing up with it .. removing it did the job ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue .. My default CSS was messing with the control .. removing it did the job ..